# Show that sigma algebra generated by subsets of R contains sigma borel algebra of R.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

So basically I want to show that if (a,b) is in F, then S(F) contains B(R). (b>a)

(Where S(F) is the sigma algebra generated by F and B(R) is the Borel sigma algebra generated by the real numbers.) So (a,b) is also in S(F), which means that the complement (-inf,a] U [b,inf) is also in S(F).

My goal now is to show that (a,b] is also in S(F), however I get stuck proving that this is the case.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**. $(a, b] = (x, b] \cap (a, y)$. What could $x, y$ be?

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer!
It is X = -inf and Y = inf, I was however probably not clear enough in my question, showing that (a,inf) is in the algebra was no problem, however I have been stuck trying to show that (-inf, b] is.

Comment: You have $A = (-\infty, a] \cup [b, \infty)$ This is enough if you take $y$ finite. If you want $(-\infty, a]$ then just intersect $A$ with $(-\infty, a+\epsilon)$.

Comment: I forgot to add one condition, b > a.
And how do we know that (-inf, a + epsilon) is in S(F)?

Comment: I'm really confused. A single interval $(a, b)$ most certainly does not generate $B(\mathbb R)$. I assumed $(a, b) \in F$ for any pair $a, b$ of finite numbers. Are you assuming something different? How did you derive that $(a, \infty) \in F$?

Comment: Your assumption is right, it is any pair of finite a,b where (a,b) is in F and b>a.

First I took the complement of (a,b), and got (-inf,a] U [b,inf) which is also in S(F), right? Then I took the complement of (-inf,a] to get (a,inf) which would also be in the algebra, so (a,inf) would be in S(F), would it not?

Comment: How did you take the complement of $(-\infty, a]$ if you only had $(\infty, a] \cup [b, \infty)$? I would suggest using an infinite union to get $(-\infty, a)$, complements to get $(-\infty, a]$ and their intersections to get all of the rest.

Comment: First I took the complement of (a,b) to get (-inf,A] U [B,inf), after that I took the complement of (-inf,A] to get (a,inf).

Comment: The operation *take-one-disjoint-component* is not in the usual definition of a $\sigma$-algebra. $(-\infty, a] \cup [b, \infty)$ is one set as good as any other.

Comment: Yeah now I see where you're coming from, then I must probably go back to the textbook and refresh my memory. Thank you for your help.